# Using scipy.signals.find_peaks() to remove large peaks

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using the scipy.signals function called find_peaks() but I might use it wrong. This is my data :
[initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezHod.png)

And I want to remove the first big peak. Unfortunately, when I use the function find_peaks, it only detects the maximum value of the peak and not the ascending part and descending part of it. Do you know which parameters I can use to do so ?

If you want a closer look to the peak here it is :
[zoom on peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9JZm.png)

Thanks a lot

Comment: `find_peaks()` only finds the peaks of the peaks. If you want to determine the boundaries of the whole peak, you need something more sophisticated. Probably you have to code it yourself.

Comment: do a moving average and discard outliers that are a certain amount of times higher than the moving average.

Comment: I want to keep the noise as it is, do you have an example of the code and how to do so. I already did a moving average myself but maybe is there a python function to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

On some advices I got, I did a moving average and removed values above a certain value (1.5*mean) and it works ok as I can obtain something like this (above is the initial data, in the middle the peaks and below the data without peaks): [triple graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOf6T.png)